# Bayes Theorem chaining

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Is this statement true

> $P(A|B)=P(A|C) \times P(C|B)$

If yes, how to prove it? If no, what should be minimal conditions on A, B and C for this to hold true?

Thanks for help.

Comment: It’s not always true. Let $X$ be the random variable that is the result of rolling a standard die. Let $A$ be $X\in\{1,2\}$, let $B$ be $X\in\{2,3\}$, and let $C$ be $X=4$. Then your statement says that $\frac{1}{2}=0\times0$.

Comment: If $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A \cap C$ and $C \cap B$ are both $ \not \emptyset$ then this statement is false?

Answer (score 0):

I think the statement is false. A counter example would be welcome.

Here is a true statement. Let $C_i$ for $i=1..n$ a partition of $\Omega$, then we can write:

> $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{P(A,B,C_i)}{P(B)}}$
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{P(A|B,C_i)\times P(C_i|B)} $

Answers, enlightenments are still very welcome.